# Redirect all subdomain to main domain .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, http-redirect

I have a Multi blogging Site and have unlimited sub-domain
now i want to move or make Nich site. so I want to redirect all sub-domain to main domain using **.htaccess**

Is it possible? 
If Possible how?

Comment: Are those subdomain using their separate directories or sharing same `DocumentRoot` as the main domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it will work

**.htaccess code:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^xyz\.php($|/) http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

The first line addresses the subdomain (case insensitive) The second line redirects all sites Except the specified xyz.php to the main domain (301)